# Make a lazy p:dataTable responsive

Tags: primefaces, responsive

I have a primefaces dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{value}" rows="#{rows}" lazy="true"
        paginator="true" reflow="true" >
```

When resizing the screen, reflow isn't working. Is this due to the `lazy="true"` attribute? The primefaces showcase responsive datatable is working without lazy...

I'm using Primefaces 6.

Comment: "Isn't working" is not smart. Investigate if the client-side html has relevant css/tags/... if there client-side is a difference in the html when using lazy and not using lazy. Lots of things to investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bet. I was using Safari 11 with design mode. Chrome 62 and Firefox 54 (both in design mode) show the reflow feature as it should we resizing the screen. Safari 11 however messes up the layout. Most of the times when resizing the screen in Safari it doesn't work. Sometimes it works, but the layout is somewhat messed up.

Chrome working example (same in Firefox):

[image]

Safari wrong reflow:

[image]

Note: please don't mind the layout, the datatable reflow styles are still under development.